# What is the basic difference between Auto Layout and Auto Resizing in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, autoresize, ios-autolayout

I have been searching the proper difference between Auto Layout and Auto Resizing, but didn't able to find the exact answer. Where I can use "Auto Layout" and where "Auto Resizing" in app? Any help would be a part of thanks.

Comment: Check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Matt Neuburg states in [his book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_layout):

> Autoresizing is a matter of conceptually assigning a subview “springs
>   and struts.” A spring can stretch; a strut can’t. Springs and struts
>   can be assigned internally or externally. Thus you can specify (using
>   internal springs and struts) whether and how the view can be resized,
>   and (using external springs and struts) whether and how the view can
>   be repositioned.

And

> Autolayout, depends on the constraints of views. A constraint (an
>   instance of NSLayoutConstraint) is much more sophisticated than the
>   "autoresizingMask" it’s a full-fledged object with numeric values, and
>   can describe a relationship between any two views (not just a subview
>   and its superview).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend watching the WWDC 2012 session https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202

Auto Layout is a new way to define dynamic GUIs. Before, we had autoresizing masks, that described how a subview will resize or move when its superview is resized. With Auto Layout you can do the same and also a lot more complicated GUIs quite easily.

Autoresizing is one of the most useful property for layouting the views in their hierarchies.
go through this link.

http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html

Comment: The techpaa link is broken it looks like

Answer (score 2):

**AutoResizing :**  Autoresizing means that how the content of a view will fit to the view. It probably depends on the self content of the view.

**AutoLayout:**  AutoLayout means how the external constraints like    the position of the view , the size of view supported  by the other neighboring  components.

AutoLayout triggers the  AutoResizing Task and  for   autoresizing activity   , auto-layout  forcefully or normally change or break  the default constraints  of views which are related to the corresponding view if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use autolayout in the superview with constraints [this helps when there are changes in the space in the View due to different devices(such as 3.5 or 4 inches retina)] and use autoresize for resizing the GUI objects in a view [this helps when there are changes in the space in the View during the orientation of the device]