# Confuse in choosing autolayout in storyboard?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am under one project.In that I am using some image files and some button.
When i use to place button in my viewcontroller and see that preview using 
assistants editor. My button are mis placed in different places.so i thought to use autolayout.But small confuse in that. I am beginner to ios.I have some question?

**METHOD 1**

**When I uncheck this autolayout option like image (A)shown below.its working perfect in all iphone simulator(3.5, 4, 4.5, 5.5). By setting autolayout using below option (B)**

**[A]** [image]

**[B]** [image]

**METHOD 2**

**At the same time when i put check mark autolayout option and use like this image show below.I am getting some misplace (Not in arrangement].I know I miss some constraints.But its not better than my above question**

[image]

please give me some suggestion about this.Which one should I use?
METHOD 1 (OR) METHOD 2.  I am new to ios .kindly suggest me something about this?

Answer (score 2):

**Method 2! Autolayout.** It is very powerful and (if you get the hang of it) quite easy and intuitive to use. You can create pretty much arbitrarily complex user interfaces using it. It has its limits, but in most of the cases you don't encounter them and most of the times they are fixable using constraints set up via code instead of the interface builder if needed.

*Method 1* was fine while it was the only option and may still be okay for simple layouts. But as soon as you want to have a little bit more complex relations between different UI elements, like one UILabel being half the size of a UIImage, you will run against a wall.

Comment: @uk2302  Thanks for your answer. I have three label ,three textfield ,2 button. shall i move with method 1 or method 2.

Comment: @spikesa if you can do it with method 1 you can keep it, but if the ui might get more complex in the future you have to move to autolayout anyway. Therefore you can just use autolayout from the beginning any way. It is your decission. I personally only use autolayout, no matter how easy a given UI is.

Comment: ok thanks for your replay.i have one more question for you.if i have less ui elements,then if i move with method 1.while submit my app in app store.does they will reject my app because of use method 1...is there any rules like that?

Comment: @spikesa No, I have never heard of one - if you would not be allowed to use method 1 apply would not present the option in Xcode. You app only might get rejected if the layout breaks on some devices or orientations which should not happen either if you use method 1 or 2 correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563128/what-is-the-basic-difference-between-auto-layout-and-auto-resizing-in-ios) for differences between autolayout(Method 1) and autoresizing mask(Method 2). Apple suggests devs to have their view layouting using Autolayout so there is not actually a question in here.

You probably messed up with constraints as every beginner does so I would recommend you to take a time in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and try to finish [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.will look at this !